# Trying to make a clock on html with Javascript, but my script isn't working. the clock doesn't actually run

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I need to make a clock that works in real-time but the actual clock isn't changing. The CSS and HTML seem to work but the javascript doesn't.

I can't seem to figure out what it could be. I'm pretty sure the javascript file is linked to the HTML file since the CSS one is.  Maybe it might have to do with some settings on my PC? like the script might be linked to the HTML but it isn't getting the right time input from somewhere else? I'm honestly completely lost.

```js
var d, h, m, s, animate;

function init() {
  d = new Date();
  h = d.getHours();
  m = d.getMinutes();
  s = d.getSeconds();
  clock();
};

function clock() {
  s++;
  if (s == 60) {
    s = 0;
    m++;
    if (m == 60) {
      m = 0;
      h++;
      if (h == 24) {
        h = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  $('sec', s);
  $('min', m);
  $('hr', h);
  animate = setTimeout(clock, 1000);
};

function $(id, val) {
  if (val < 10) {
    val = '0' + val;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};

window.onload = init;
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Epilogue;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.clock {
  text-align: center;
  width: center;
  height: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span id="hr">00</span>
  <span> : </span>
  <span id="min">00</span>
  <span> : </span>
  <span id="sec">00</span>
</div>
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Bin.png)

Comment: Actually it works pretty fine for me.

Comment: It works fine as long as the window.onload statement is in the same place as the rest of the script.

Comment: do you know any reason it wouldn't be working for me?

Comment: same, after splitting the CSS, HTML and JS into the respective editor field, it works just fine. YOu proberly added a wrong link to the JS script in you HTML header.

Comment: how could see where the window.init statement is?

Comment: Sorry - I meant onload - I've updated my comment

Comment: Is your script file actually called `script.js` and is it in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: Actually, no matter how I split the code (HEAD script and/or file script) or where I place the window.onload line, it works fine.

Comment: Code is fine (or js is fine, declaration and css not exactly) The only situation when it won't work is your `script.js` is not in root directory as declared or has different name

Answer (score 1):

While we're curious about why your example does not work for you, you should know that this clock is gonna be off by several minutes after just one hour. You can't rely on setTimeout which is blocked by all the code running before it.
Here's an example that would bypass the call to init and make sure your clock is always right

```
**javascript code**                

function $(id,val){
    if(val<10){
        val='0'+val;
    }
    let e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e) e.innerHTML=val;  // only update if element exists <<
};


function clock(){
    d = new Date();
    $('sec', d.getSeconds());
    $('min', d.getMinutes());
    $('hr',  d.getHours());
};

setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Comment: The only issue with that is that the clock function is not called until 1000ms has elapsed - not a huge issue, of course, but maybe do a window.onload as well just to start with something other than 0's?

Answer (score 0):

I just thought id put everything in one place for you. Your code is working fine as the comments suggest. I updated the JS as Selim suggests as well. See the comments in the code below. But just for you to see everything working together, copy all this code into your HTML file then move your JS and CSS to separate files as per the comments in the code. Make sure you link to the JS file in the correct path.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Current Time</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // MOVE THIS CODE INTO A FILE CALLED CLOCK.JS
    // SAVE THE FILE IN THE SAME FOLDER AS YOUR HTML FILE (OR A LIBRARY/JS FOLDER)
    // LINK TO THE FILE <script src="clock.js"> < /script>
     
    function $(id,val){
    
        if(val < 10){
            val = '0' + val;
        }
        let e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e) e.innerHTML = val;  
    };


    function clock(){
        d = new Date();
        $('sec', d.getSeconds());
        $('min', d.getMinutes());
        $('hr',  d.getHours());
    };
    
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* PLACE THIS CODE IN YOUR CSS FILE AND LINK TO IT AS PER JS FILE
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> */
    *{
        font-family: Epilogue;
        font-size:36px;
    }
    .clock{
        text-align:center;
        width:center;
        height:center;
    }
</style> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="clock">
     <span id = "hr" >00</span>
     <span> : </span>
     <span id = "min" >00</span>
     <span> : </span>
     <span id = "sec" >00</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```